# Why does welcome page occur 404 not found?

Tags: php, laravel-10

I created a brand new Laravel Project with below command.

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel keijiban "10.*" --prefer-dist
```

I acccess this URL (http://localhost:8000/keijiban) on two different browser.
In both browser 404 Not Found error is shown.
I checked httpd.conf to allow override.
I restart Web server with php artisan serve command.
I restarted VSCode itself.

Route is seemed correctly to set to me.

keijiban/routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

I didn't change the below file.

keijiban/resources/views/welcome.blade.php

What's wrong with this?

Laravel Framework 10.12.0

PHP 8.2.4 (cli) (built: Mar 14 2023 17:54:25) (ZTS Visual C++ 2019 x64)

[image]

Comment: When you run `php artisan serve` (from your project folder) your URL will be `http://localhost:8000`, not `http://localhost:8000/keijiban`.

Comment: fyi, `httpd.conf` is not involved when you use `php artisan serve`.

Answer (score 2):

You are requesting the `/keijiban` route but your code only specifies the `/` route.

```
Route::get('/keijiban', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```